# Format Library Dependencies For Magick++

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, imagemagick, magick++

I want to compile ImageMagick the C++ version on android, the Magick++ documentation seems simple but doesn't show a definitive list of compatible formats like jpeg, gif etc and whether these require installation of the requirements such as libjpeg, libpng.

ImageMagick itself shows this list, so it's suffice to say that included formats like webp and tiff will also work in Magick++, but...

1. do they require download and installation of their respective librarires?
2. and if so, will their C libraries work or do they have to be made into .cpps?
3. Do I have to also compile the "coders" module which has C files corresponding to each format?

Answer (score 2):

Magick++ is a C++ API to the C methods of ImageMagick. This means that reading and writing the different formats will be handled in the C part. If you want support for jpeg you need to link the coders module with libjpeg. Below is an answer to your sub questions:

1. Yes they do, if you want support for png you need libpng.
2. You can just use the C libraries.
3. The coders module handles reading and writing the different image formats so you definitely need this.